# How to resolve buffered reader issues while writing to synapse dedicated sql pool tables from Azure databricks using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, pyarrow, apache-arrow

We have delta tables built on top of the ADLS Gen2 in Azure Databricks.

I want to push the data to Synapse dedicated sql pool tables using COPY command but I get issues while loading the data related to HdfsBridge, BufferedReader, MUST have 12 bytes etc etc

It all resulted into me having to widen the data types of the synapse table  e.g. from int to bigint, from datetime to datetime2(7) etc

My question is : Is there a way to handle this without altering the data types controlling the parquet files that are generated as staging file ( I remember one blog mentioning something about apache arrow) ?

Comment: Post your code. Specifically if you're reading a DataFrame from a delta table and writing it to Synapse then post `df.schema` of what you read and what you write. Also post the DDL of target Synapse table if already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was able to make it work by

1. first using "overwrite" mode which gave me the exact stricture that spark is trying to create in synapse
2. then I used it compare the data types against my table ddl and found the mismatch and changed that column alone
3. recreated the table from the SSMS
4. changed the pyspark code back to append mode
5. Load was successful